# Pixelated Explorer Icon

Tags: qt, icons, windows-explorer

I'm using Qt to create an application. When I produce the executable however, the image comes out rather blurry

[image: Pixelated icon]

[image: Regular icon]

As shown the image .ico source displays perfectly but the application's icon is not quite right. Is there some technical reason why this is occurring and a way to fix it?

Comment: what are the dimensions on the icon you are using? It's probably just a resolution issue.

Comment: Make sure your icon file has many different sizes, every icon file can contain many sizes, if window can't find the size it needs it resizes.

Comment: @OmerPT Would you just list the icons in the resource file? Is there some special protocol to it?

Comment: What software are you using to create the .ico file? all the sizes are supposed to be hardcoded into the file.

Comment: I'm using Qt, but the way to do this is via a resource file. The icon is currently included by doing `IDI_ICON1 ICON DISCARDABLE "wing48.ico"` so what I'm asking is would you just do `IDI_ICON2...` with the other icon sizes?

Comment: No, all the sizes should be in one file and it's the ico file.
I'm asking where you got that wing icon from, what software you used to create it as an .ico file? or you just got it off the internet?

Comment: I have sizes 16x16, 32, 48, 64, 128, 256. Originally .png files which I've turned to .ico using Gimp.

Comment: Did you put them all into one file? if so then I don't know what's causing the blurriness.

Comment: They all go in one .ico?

Comment: Yep... Usually you just need to put the biggest one and tell Gimp to make all versions... I'll try downloading Gimp and see how it works there so I can give you further help

Comment: Well from what I see gimp doesn't give you much to work with.... 
You can try downloading a trial of http://www.axialis.com/iconworkshop/
If you don't plan on using icons in the future...

Comment: Do you mind me asking what was the problem?

Comment: Well I figured out that I just needed the clear the icon cache and restart explorer. However I also found that Microsoft goes so far as the recommend 16x16, 32x32, 48x48 icons at a minimum so I did opt to do that. The 48x48 I was supplying orignally wasn't showing because I first tried a 32x32 that was cached.